# Reconnecting two sql tables using mutual id from third table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, alter-table

Suppose we have three SQL tables A,B and C:

```
TABLE A { id, c_id}

TABLE B {id, c_id}

TABLE C {id}
```

So A and B have foreign keys from table C. I created a column in Table A that will reference Table B:

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD COLUMN b_id INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE A ADD FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B(id);
```

All the tables are in production and filled with data.

What i need to figure out is how to populate this new column for every row and i need a SQL query or a hint that will help me to remap `A` to `B` based on a `c_id` in both of them.

So i need to get just one of many `b_id` from `B` for each row in A based on a mutual `c_id` and insert it for each row.

The business rule says just to use any (first) `b_id` when there are more of them.

After that i'll drop the `c_id` in Table `A`.

Comment: What RDBMS (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, ...) do you use ?

Comment: Huh, sorry..Postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be:

```
UPDATE A  
SET b_id = t.b_ID
FROM (select min(id) as b_Id,c_id FROM B Group by c_id ) AS t
WHERE A.c_id = t.c_id
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b9ca4/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, you're the Haxor of the day :)